# Limit number of rows displayed in SQL without limiting number of rows selected

Tags: mysql, sql

In order to export data through my web hosting service's SQL interface, I have to first run a SELECT call on the table and then click an "export" button at the bottom of the output. The problem is that I am sometimes trying to export hundreds of thousands of rows, and my browser crashes trying to display them all.

Is there a way to limit the number of rows *displayed* from a SQL call without limiting the rows actually selected? I know that it's possible to export the data directly through the SQL call, but that's pretty far above my pay grade (I tried doing it but I'm getting an access denied error, and I'd like to avoid having to figure that out if I can). I'm pretty new to SQL, so this might be a dumb question (like, I could imagine the number of rows displayed being entirely a property of the interface, not SQL itself) -- but I figured I'd ask anyway :)

Comment: Well how do you display the rows currently? Simply count the rows you want to output through your Interface and ignore those beyond that count.

Comment: The interface automatically displays all hundreds of thousands of them. But the problem is that I need to export all of those rows, but my browser can't handle displaying them. (Like, I want to export all of them without having to display all of them, if that makes sense.)

Comment: I am afraid you will need to issue 2 requests: one with LIMIT option for display purposes and another without LIMIT option for export.

Comment: @slkorolev sad :( but makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Your issue is your interface; what is it?

Comment: @Martin adminer. Yeah, I really don't like it. But I can't change it (it's through my work)

Comment: @AdamMorris the problem is not the SQL; the SQL always returns exactly what you ask for or returns an error. Weather you choose to *display* what is returned is never a choice SQL makes; it simply hands you -- or Admirer - the data, so if the issue is the display is timing out you need to take this up either with your Work (use a better interface such as MySQL Workbench etc.), or contact Admirer tech/dev support to request how to workaround their program.